# POSTGIS: ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries. Trying to find overlapping geoms with two different SRIDS/tables

Tags: sql, transform, postgis, intersect, srid

POSTGIS_VERSION=2.1;

I have two tables with two different SRID. My objective is to show which geoms from TABLE_B intersect with a region from TABLE_A.

```
SELECT tablebname, a.geom FROM TABLE_B as a INNER JOIN (SELECT geom FROM TABLE_A WHERE tableAID = '00001') as b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

My table structure (truncated) is as follows

TABLE_A
text tableAid
geometry geom  (SRID=3577)

TABLE_B
text tableBid
geometry geom  (SRID=4326)

I have tried transforming the geoms with ST_TRANSFORM(geom, 3577) but I still get the same error "ERROR: Operation on mixed SRID geometries."

Using the following command 
`select distinct(ST_SRID(geom)) as srid, count(*) from tableA group by srid;`

I get the following

```
srid | count
3566 | 2196
     |   18
```

My attempts at changing the last 18 to 3577 are futile. Each time I update the SRID it says it succeeded or did not find any SRID <> 3577.

Any help would be appriciated. I can provided more details in required. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PostGIS? The 18 counts without SRIDs are possibly NULL.

Comment: I have the same issue under Debian Stretch but when I run from the command line with psql -d"mydb" -c "SELECT ..." it works perfectly showing that its a problem inside pycopg2 specifically. Could you fix it?

Comment: Scratching the very bottom of my memory, if I recall correctly, I may have just set all the NULL SRIDs to 1 or matched them with the SRID of the rest of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a subquery, correcting the table alias, and using a transform, does this work?

```
SELECT b.*, a.*
FROM table_b AS b
INNER JOIN table_a AS a ON
  tableaid = '00001' AND ST_Intersects(ST_Transform(a.geom, 4326), b.geom);
```

Also note that in your original query, you confuse `TABLE_B as a`, which possibly explains why your attempt with ST_Transform failed, since it wasn't transforming the intended `a.geom` column. Furthermore, there is no such version of PostGIS 9.1, so I'm guessing you have 2.x. If setup using typmods (e.g., `geometry(Polygon, 4326)`), these cannot have mixed SRIDs.

Comment: Thanks Mike, while the SQL query executes it does not return any matches. I know that regions I have do overlap however none are return by the query. Do you have a possible explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Your SQL query did work in finding neighboring (intersecting) regions on the same table. I do require intersecting regions across tables. Any further help you can provided is appreciated. I will continue to tackle the problem and let you know of any developments.

Comment: Your SQL was correct, I was using the wrong SRID on both tables.